# How to run a keyboard macro (saved in my init.el) automatically when Emacs starts up?

Tags: microsoft-windows, start-up, keyboard-macros

I have saved a keyboard macro in my `init.el` file as follows

```
(fset 'remember-notes-my-macro
   (lambda (&optional arg)
     "Keyboard macro."
     (interactive "p")
     (kmacro-exec-ring-item
       (quote ([134217848 114 101 109 101 109 98 101 114 45
                110 111 116 101 115 return 134217848 114 101
                99 111 118 101 114 45 116 104 105 115 45 102
                105 108 101 return 121 101 115 return] 0 "%d"))
     arg)))
```

I want to run this macro **automatically** when Emacs starts up. I tried to add the line `(remember-notes-my-macro)` in my `init.el` to run it when Emacs is launched, but I got a fatal error at startup.

[image]

I have never debugged Emacs, so I don't know what to do about it. The macro **runs fine** with `M-x remember-notes-my-macro` when Emacs is already running.

How can I get the macro to run automatically at startup?

**Note:** What this macro does is, it runs `remember-notes` to open notes. Then it runs `recover-this-file` to recover autosave data and then it enters *yes* at the minibuffer prompt.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: *Always* quote the error message (if any) when asking a question.

Comment: @NickD, I have added a screenshot of the dialog box to the question. I have never debugged Emacs with gdb, so I don't know how to do it. Should I attach the emacs_backtrace.txt too?

Comment: @phils please see my comment above

Comment: Oh, you really did mean a fatal error.  Please `M-x report-emacs-bug` -- S.E. isn't the right place to address an issue with Emacs crashing.

Comment: Maybe the fatal error is due to the function being interactive - I suggest trying without `(interactive "p")`

Comment: @ChanheeJeong I did not type out the elisp code myself. I used `M-x insert-kbd-macro` to autogenerate the elisp code. Should I still edit it by hand?